# Frequency by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following variables day (weekdays from 1-7) and time variables t1 till t7 that record activities performed during a specific time.

I would like to identify how many times the same activity occurs over the 7 weekdays for each homologous time slot.

Input:

```
day t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7
   1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
   1  1  0  1  0  4  0  1
   4  2  3  1  0  1  0  1
   5  1  1  1  0  0  0  1
```

Output:

```
time   Most frequent
t1     1    
t2     0,1,3       
t3     1
t4     0
t5     0
t6     0
t7     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-day) %>% 
  group_by(name,value) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(freq = n()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(freq == max(freq)) %>% 
  select(name, value) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(`Most frequent` = paste(value, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  rename(time = name)
```

Which gives:

```
  time  `Most frequent`
  <chr> <chr>          
1 t1    1              
2 t2    0,3,1          
3 t3    1              
4 t4    0              
5 t5    0              
6 t6    0              
7 t7    1
```

Here is the code with some comments:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-day) %>% # Structuring data in long format
  group_by(name,value) %>% # Grouping by name(t#) and value(activity)
  distinct() %>%  # Selecting distinct instances of time + activity (i.e. day + t#)
  mutate(freq = n()) %>% # Counting unique occurances of time + activity
  group_by(name) %>% # Grouping by time
  filter(freq == max(freq)) %>% # Filtering to select only the most frequent cases
  select(name, value) %>% # Selecting only the variables name and value
  distinct() %>% # Filtering for unique occurances
  group_by(name) %>% # Grouping by name (time)
  summarise(`Most frequent` = paste(value, collapse = ",")) %>% # Aggregating by time, pasting values on separate rows together with a comma separating the values
  rename(time = name) # Renaming variable name to time
```

Comment: many thanks could you please explain the code. thanks

Comment: Sure I will type something up, but perhaps a better way of understanding the code would be to start at the very top and observe each action before the next pipe `%>%`. For example, first run `df %>% pivot_longer(-day)` and see how that transforms your data. Then run `df %>% pivot_longer(-day) %>% group_by(name, value)` etc..